# Clarification on the Azure B2C pricing for login / authorize request

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

It is not clear if Azure B2C Authentication pricing is applicable on every request, even when there is failed authentication or only when authentication is successful and after a token is issued.

We will be performing silentauthentication to check user status in B2C. And this will be done frequently on every action unless user has logged in.
So it will impact our costing if every request to authorize endpoint is charged.

Copied below content from the Azure B2C pricing page https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/active-directory-b2c/

Authentications: **tokens issued either in response to a sign-in request** initiated by a user or initiated by an application on behalf of a user (e.g. token refresh, where the refresh interval is configurable)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a B2C expert but I would suggest you enable reporting on a small number of users so you can estimate the expected monthly cost of your Azure AD B2C tenant activity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-usage-reporting-api